# Errors with cPanel Pear Mail: failed to open stream

Tags: php, pear, cpanel

I've installed Pear via the cPanel installer, and installed the Mail package (which also automatically installed Net_Mail and Net_Socket packages). However from my PHP file wherein I send email I get the following error:

> **Warning:** include_once(Net/SMTP.php)
>   [function.include-once]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory
>   in /**usr/local/lib/php/Mail/smtp.php** on
>   line **348**
>
> **Warning:** include_once()
>   [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'Net/SMTP.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   in **/usr/local/lib/php/Mail/smtp.php** on
>   line **348**
>
> **Fatal error**: Class 'Net_SMTP' not
>   found
>   in **/usr/local/lib/php/Mail/smtp.php** on
>   line **349**

Now I have checked the includes, the paths, and all of them check out fine and are in the appropriate locations and have appropriate permissions.

How do I resolve this error?

For reference here's the directory structure (omitting other folders):

```
php
|-Mail
| |-mail.php
| |-mock.php
| |-null.php
| |-RFC822.php
| |-sendmail.php
| |-smtp.php
| |-smtpmx.php
|-Net
| |-SMTP.php
| |-Socket.php
|- Mail.php
```

Comment: Could you print your folder scheme? Have you looked for `/usr/local/lib/php/Mail/smtp.php`?

Comment: @Charlie please refer to my updated post... I approximated the folder structure using ASCII.

Comment: I don't know. This problem occurred to me multiple times and it was always about the path which was not correct. You are might looking at a specific project editing another. I don't know it could be everything...

Comment: Which folder did you ascii-print? (full path needed)

Answer (score 6):

If you have ssh access you can try:

```
pear install Net_SMTP
```